# google visualization dataTableToCsv

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using google.visualization.dataTableToCsv to create an Array I can iterate through to populate a Google Timeline chart. The data is coming from a Google Sheet. This is working well, except that strings with commas are getting separated when I use the split function. Is there a better method of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the following function to fix this issue

```
function CSVtoArray(text) {
    var re_valid = /^\s*(?:'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|[^,'"\s\\]*(?:\s+[^,'"\s\\]+)*)\s*(?:,\s*(?:'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"|[^,'"\s\\]*(?:\s+[^,'"\s\\]+)*)\s*)*$/;
    var re_value = /(?!\s*$)\s*(?:'([^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*)'|"([^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*)"|([^,'"\s\\]*(?:\s+[^,'"\s\\]+)*))\s*(?:,|$)/g;

    // Return NULL if input string is not well formed CSV string.
    if (!re_valid.test(text)) return null;

    var a = []; // Initialize array to receive values.
    text.replace(re_value, // "Walk" the string using replace with callback.
        function(m0, m1, m2, m3) {

            // Remove backslash from \' in single quoted values.
            if (m1 !== undefined) a.push(m1.replace(/\\'/g, "'"));

            // Remove backslash from \" in double quoted values.
            else if (m2 !== undefined) a.push(m2.replace(/\\"/g, '"'));
            else if (m3 !== undefined) a.push(m3);
            return ''; // Return empty string.
        });

    // Handle special case of empty last value.
    if (/,\s*$/.test(text)) a.push('');
    return a;
};
```